# MS Access query that includes a join to itself (using a subquery) and reports values that do not exist (null values)

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, subquery

I have the following table named PRICES:

| VERTEXID | TIMEID | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6001 | 20191231 | 104.3 |
| 6001 | 20181231 | 115.3 |
| 6001 | 20171231 | 138.3 |
| 6001 | 20161231 | 122.3 |
| 6002 | 20191231 | 102.3 |
| 6002 | 20190931 | 123.3 |
| 6002 | 20190631 | 167.3 |
| 6002 | 20181231 | 202.3 |
| 6002 | 20171231 | 402.3 |
| 6002 | 20170931 | 162.3 |

I want to write a query in **MS Access sql** that will find the top 5 TIMEIDs in the table ordered in a descending order and then will return the corresponding values **for each** VERTEXID I select in the WHERE clause. If the record does not exist I want the query to return the previous value that exists (this is preferred) or null. Here's an example of the output I need:

| VERTEXID | TIMEID | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6001 | 20191231 | 104.3 |
| 6001 | 20190931 | 104.3 (or null) |
| 6001 | 20190631 | 104.3 (or null) |
| 6001 | 20181231 | 115.3 |
| 6001 | 20171231 | 138.3 |
| 6002 | 20191231 | 102.3 |
| 6002 | 20190931 | 123.3 |
| 6002 | 20190631 | 167.3 |
| 6002 | 20181231 | 202.3 |
| 6002 | 20171231 | 402.3 |

What I have so far is this:

```
SELECT P1.VERTEXID, P1.TIMEID, P1.PRICE
FROM PRICES P1
RIGHT JOIN (
                        SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 P2.TIMEID
                        FROM   PRICES P2
                        WHERE   P2.TIMEID <= 20191231
                        ORDER BY P2.TIMEID DESC
                        ) P3
            ON P3.TIMEID = P1.TIMEID
WHERE P1.VERTEXID IN (6001,6002) AND P1.TIMEID <= 20191231
ORDER BY P1.VERTEXID, P1.TIMEID DESC
```

but it will not output what I need. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm lost.  Your results have more than 5 timeids.  But you way you only want the top five.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes but I need only the top 5 that exist in the table for each VERTEXID. But these top 5 TIMEIDs need to be the same for each VERTEXID as in my example output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

```
SELECT J1.VERTEXID, J1.TIMEID, P4.PRICE
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT P1.VERTEXID, P3.TIMEID
    FROM PRICES P1,
            (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 P2.TIMEID
            FROM PRICES P2
            WHERE P2.TIMEID <= 20191231
            ORDER BY P2.TIMEID DESC
            ) P3
    ) J1
LEFT JOIN PRICES P4 ON J1.VERTEXID = P4.VERTEXID AND J1.TIMEID = P4.TIMEID
ORDER BY J1.VERTEXID, J1.TIMEID DESC
```

You have to add your filter conditions, as you need.

Basically you have to do the following:

- do a `CROSS JOIN` to get all combinations of VERTEXID and TIMEID (that's `J1`)
- then `LEFT JOIN` this result to the table itself and get the according PRICE values

Missing prices will be NULL.

Comment: This works perfectly.  I run it though on a table with a lot of entries and I was wondering if there is a way to speed it up as much as possible?

Comment: Due to the `CROSS JOIN` you are getting a lot of intermediate results. That slows down the query. You can try to filter that query as much as possible and use indexes on VERTEXID and TIMEID.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent 5 rows for each vertex id:

```
select p.*
from prices as p
where p.vertexid in (6001, 6002) and
      p.timeid in (select top 5 p2.timeid
                   from prices as p2
                   where p2.vertexid = p.vertexid
                   order by p2.timeid desc
                  );
```

You have filtering on the time in your query, but this is not mentioned in the actual question you ask.  Given that the filtering is on `timeid`, you can just put it in the subquery if you need it.

EDIT:

If you want the same five time ids (if they are present) for all vertexids, you can use:

```
select p.*
from prices as p
where p.vertexid in (6001, 6002) and
      p.timeid in (select top 5 p2.timeid
                   from prices as p2
                   where p2.vertexid in (6001, 6002)
                   order by p2.timeid desc
                  );
```

If you want only shared timeids for the two vertices, you can use:

```
      p.timeid in (select top 5 p2.timeid
                   from prices as p2
                   where p2.vertexid in (6001, 6002)
                   group by p2.timeid
                   having count(*) = 2
                   order by p2.timeid desc
                  );
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it seems it's not producing the output I need. The same 5 TIMEIDs need to exist for each VERTEXID. If not then the latest TIMEID value should be used. So in my example the result should always include 10 entries (2 VERTEXIDs * TOP 5 TIMEIDs). In your query I get 10 records but not the same TIMEIDs for each VERTEXID.

Comment: I added 'distinct top 5' in the subquery because it was returning TIMEIDs for both VERTEXIDs and now I get the common TIMEIDs for each VERTEXID and 2 more for 6002 which are not shared. I want the query to return these 2 (TIMEIDs: 20190931, 20190631) for VERTEXID 6001 with the value of 104.3 - VERTEXID: 6001, TIMEID: 20191231 as in my example output. Is that possible?

Comment: Your second edit works as you describe but this is not what I need. Please see my previous comment or the example output table in my question.